# why does the compiler performs idiv and cdq for unsigned integers

Tags: compiler-construction, unsigned, signed

I'm very curious to know why the following code snippet is compiled with cdq and idiv operations, which belong to signed integers. The code doesn't contain any signed integers, however. I was thinking maybe this is an optimization? I would be really happy to know.

```
typedef struct mfiu
{
    struct
    {
        uint32_t field_code : 24;
        uint32_t inc_size : 1;
        uint32_t reserved_0 : 7;
    };
    uint32_t raw;
} mfiu_t;

typedef struct mls
{
    mfiu_t field_id;
    uint16_t num_of_fields;
    uint16_t num_of_elem;
    uint32_t offset;

} mls_t;

typedef struct lis
{
    mfiu_t field_id;
} lis_t;


int foo(lis_t* lookup_context, mls_t* entry){
    uint16_t element_stride = (uint16_t)entry->field_id.inc_size + 1;
    uint32_t field_num = (lookup_context->field_id.field_code - entry->field_id.field_code) /
                             (entry->num_of_elem * element_stride);
    uint32_t elem_num = (lookup_context->field_id.field_code - entry->field_id.field_code) /
                             element_stride;
    return 0;
}
```

using clang 9.0 as an example, both of the division operations are performed via idiv:

```
mov     eax, r9d ; entry->num_of_elem * element_stride
cdq              ;lookup_context->field_id.field_code - entry->field_id.field_code is extended to signed bit for some reason
idiv    r10d
```

and the second one:

```
movzx   r9d, word ptr [rbp - 18] ; element_stride
cdq                              ; lookup_context->field_id.field_code - entry->field_id.field_code is also signed extended to a 64bit integer
idiv    r9d
```

The compiled code can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vG1TKodK6).

Thank you!

Comment: At a guess, the `uint16_t` variable gets promoted to `int`.

Comment: the cdq is for the substruction, so the substruction of the two 24bit fields is sign-extended for some reason. I'm really confused.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you do `... ((uint32_t) entry->num_of_elem * (uint32_t) element_stride)` ?

Comment: yes, in fact, I believe the problem is that bit fields are first converted to integers: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-in-a/0596006977/ch04.html therefore the compiler believes that the substruction might produce a value that is beyind the 24 bits, promoting it to an integer. what do you think?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I thought also.

Comment: cool, you can write (if you will of course) an official answer in this thread :) and thanks!